# How to get children's of item using odata service in sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api, odata

[image]

I need to get all the children of the below folder structure using the Sitecore OData service.

Is there any way to get all the children without the folder structure, meaning all items under "Resource Testing" should be at the same level?

I tried with multiple services but it's only returning only the 2nd ones (see to the image above with highlighted section) .

```
https://host/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('/sitecore/content/LittelfuseJSS/Data%20Source/WebDAM%20Assets/Resources%20Testing')/Children?$expand=FieldValues($select=fileName,assetId,Id),StandardFieldValues($select=__Created_by,__Updated_by)&sc_apikey={AF26FAB8-D61E-4664-A21C-969E24D14076}&$select=ID,Name
```